# Multiple queries in pgrouting (length as result)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am facing the following problem with two tables:

The first table contains **all** my streetnetwork with cost, source, target. Another table contains 60 nodes (from the above network). Between all these 60 nodes I want to calculate the length of the path (e.g.: from node 1 to 2,3,4...60, from node 2 to 1,3,4,5...60 etc.)

Do you have a solution which could automatically calculate the length of all paths? Until now I can just calculate manually one path, then save the table and calculate the length.

But as you can imagine I don't wanna calculate 60*60 relations manually.

See my SQL-query so far:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, a.cost, geom_way
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
'SELECT id, source, target, km as cost, km as reverse_cost FROM 
routing where cost is not null',
(SELECT nodes FROM nodelist WHERE id =1),
(SELECT nodes FROM nodelist WHERE id =2), 
false, 
true
) AS a
Join routing b
ON a.id2 = b.id
ORDER BY seq;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pgr_kDijkstra`](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.1/src/kdijkstra/doc/index.html#pgr-kdijkstra) to compute the path or total cost from 1 node to many. There is no function so far for many-to-many calculations, but the one above should already be a lot better.

The [pgRouting workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html#multiple-shortest-paths-with-kdijkstra) also explains how to use `pgr_kDijkstra`:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS source, id2 AS target, cost FROM pgr_kdijkstraCost('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM ways',
                10, array[60,70,80], false, false);
```

The argument to specify target nodes must be an array of node IDs's.
You had to run this function then once for each of your 60 nodes.